# My website is not displaying correctly on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, display

i just uploaded my first website online but it is not displaying the mobile version on my iphone, it is working perfectly on my desktop computer when i try to lower the size of the internet navigator.

any suggestion ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Continue your learning by starting with [Learn Responsive Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp). Please note this has a learn curve.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have next line in the `<head></head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```